# Adding the same event handler(ajax) for same event more than one element not setting the attribute value properly in jQuery | jQuery | Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two input text box and I have added the same key up event handler which calls the ajax request. I want to perform some snippet(enable the text box) on the "complete" event but they are not working independently.

```
<input type="text" name="ele1" id="ele1">
<input type="text" name="ele2" id="ele2">

$(function() {
    let ele1 = $('#ele1');
    let ele2 = $('#ele2');
    $("#ele1, #ele2").on('keyup', resourceChange);
    function resourceChange(e) {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.prop('disabled', true);
        $.ajax({
            url: "test_upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function(xhr) {
                response = xhr.responseJSON;
                $this.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

for testing purposes, I manually add 5 seconds delay.

```
<?php
// test_upload.php
sleep(5);
$response = [
    'success' => true,
    'name' => 'test_name'
];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

**Problem:** When I type a character on the first text box, it will be disabled for the next five seconds(count down start). But If I type on second text box before complete these 5 seconds(let say., 3 seconds pass) then the first text box is never enabled. It remains to disable. and the second text box is enabled after remaining seconds from 5 seconds. (5 - 3 = 2 seconds)

Comment: if i understand you right you can send ele1 or ele2 via ajax and return it then you will know with ele u should enable

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should capture the response. And then decide what you need to do.

Try this.

```
<input type="text" name="ele1" id="ele1">
<input type="text" name="ele2" id="ele2">
<input type="text" name="ele3" id="ele3">
<input type="text" name="ele4" id="ele4">
```

---

```
$(function() {
        var respCount = 0;
        var selectedElem = [];
        let ele1 = $('#ele1');
        let ele2 = $('#ele2');
        let ele3 = $('#ele3');
        let ele4 = $('#ele4');

        var idx = 0;
        $("#ele1, #ele2, #ele3, #ele4").on('keyup', resourceChange);
        function resourceChange(e) {

            $this = $(this);
            selectedElem.push({id: $this[0].id});

            $this.prop('disabled', true);
            $.ajax({
                url: "test_upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                complete: function(xhr) {
                    response = xhr.responseJSON;

                    $(`#${selectedElem[respCount].id}`).prop('disabled', false);

                    respCount++;

                }
            });


        }



    });
```

Comment: @sachin kumar I think now you have an Idea about that. Modify the code as you wish. Thank

Comment: It is not mandatory that I always type on the first text box and then second. As your code will not works if I type on the second text box first.

Comment: In a generic way, I want to enable the text box independently ajax request hit by them. Doesn't matter how many text box I have.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one by sending element via ajax and recive it.

```
<input type="text" name="ele1" id="ele1">
<input type="text" name="ele2" id="ele2">

$(function() {
$("input").on('keyup', resourceChange);
function resourceChange(e) {
    element = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        url: "test_upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: 'element='+element,
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(xhr) {
            response = xhr.responseJSON;
            $('input[name="'+response.element+'"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
}
});
```

php

```
 <?php
// test_upload.php
sleep(5);
$response = [
  'success' => true,
  'name' => 'test_name',
  'element' => $_POST['element']
];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Your solution is also right. But I need to re-send the element from my PHP script.